# onCreate of android service not called

Tags: android, android-service

I want to start a service in a static way. So from my activity I call

```
SpeechActivationService.makeStartServiceIntent(
               this.getApplicationContext(),
               "WordActivator");
```

Here is the actual class that extends from service class http://dpaste.com/hold/928115/ As you can see there are several log points, e.g. in the onCreate method.

This is not logged. Only if I put log text in `makeStartServiceIntent` method it appears, however not in the `onCreate` method.

Here's the `makeStartServiceIntent` method:

```
public static Intent makeStartServiceIntent(Context context,
        String activationType) {        
    Intent i = new Intent(context, SpeechActivationService.class);
    i.putExtra(ACTIVATION_TYPE_INTENT_KEY, activationType);
    return i;
}
```

In manifest file I have

```
<service android:name="root.gast.speech.activation.SpeechActivationService"/>
```

Any ideas why the service is not started?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `makeStartService()` just creates an Intent for you. You don't seem to actually be firing that intent off to start the service. Try like this

```
Intent i = SpeechActivationService.makeStartServiceIntent(this,"WordActivator");
startService(i);
```

Note that if `this.getApplicationContext()` works you are likely already inside of a `Context` object so simply using `this` *should* work also.

Answer (score 12):

Aside from you not posting code showing `startService()`, it looks like the package name of your `Service` in the manifest doesn't match your `SpeechActivationService` class (**assuming the code link you posted is the actual `SpeechActivationService` class in your project, and not just a class you copied from**).

```
<service android:name="com.mkyong.android.SpeechActivationService"/>
```